# God's Nichum Aveilim

Tags: mourning-aveilus, nevua-prophecy, tosfot, maseches-kiddushin, tractate-sotah

Asking for a friend:

On [Kiddushin 38a, Tosfos s.v. Tzei](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%97_%D7%90#%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA), explain that Hashem didn't approach Yehoshua until after the 30 days of mourning for Moshe had elapsed, since the Shechinah does not descend and come unto a person during times of Aveilus, mourning. (Technically speaking, this is based on [Berachos 31a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%90), which talks about the Shechinah not coming to someone who is sad; however, Tosfos seem to view it as a connection to the technical Aveilus.)

How would Tosfos explain [Sotah 14a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%90), which states that Hashem visited Yitzchak during his period of mourning for his father?

Comment: Having trouble tagging; please help me out!

Comment: Presumably one could draw a distinction between השראת השכינה for the specific purpose of ניחום אבלים and for other matters.